# Monitor resource usage of query in InfluxDB

Tags: monitoring, influxdb

I'm running a lot of queries in InfluxDB and I'm trying to diagnose which query or queries are the most resource intensive. I know I can use `SHOW STATS` or `SHOW DIAGNOSTICS` but that doesn't show any information for specific queries. How can I get more detailed information?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to attain the details of specific queries.

- [Explain](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#explain): Parses and plans the query, and then prints a summary
  of estimated costs. More details are available.
- [Explain analyze](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#explain-analyze): Executes the query and counts the actual costs 
  during runtime.

As you mentioned in your question to monitor overall performance, other than `SHOW STATS` AND `SHOW DAIGONOSTICS` you can depend on _inernal database also. See [here](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/how-to-use-the-show-stats-command-and-the-_internal-database-to-monitor-influxdb/) for more details.